# laravel pass data from blade file to Controller

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to take data that a user inputs into a form, created in blade, and transport that data to my controller. At that point I can use a function in my controller to write the data into MySQL.

Here is the code for the form which I have in my blade file.

```
<form action="{{ route("users") }}" method="post">

<input type ="form" id="firstname"> firstname </input> <br>
<input type ="form" id="lastname"> lastname </input> <br>
<input type="form" id="email"> email </input> <br>
<input type="form" id="userlevel"> userlevel </input> <br>
<input type="form" id="password"> password </input> <br>


<br> <br>
<button type="submit"> Submit
</button>
</form>
```

Here is the code in my controller which writes data into MySQL. The code works when I am using dummy data, instead of the `$name` and `$lastname` variables.

```
public function users()
{
    $name = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];

    DB :: table("newUsers") -> insertGetId
    (
        array("firstname" => $name, "lastname" => $lastname, "email" => "test")
    );

    return view("pages.users");
}
```

I am currently getting an error that says

> Undefined index: firstname

Ideally what I want to happen is for whatever the user entered for firstname and lastname to be written into my MySQL table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `name` attributes to your inputs and format them correctly they should look more like:

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"></input>
```

If you are placing 'firstname' between your openning and closing input tags for a placholder value use the placeholder attribute instead.

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="first name"></input>
```

But do be warned the placeholder attribute doesnt work in [older browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder)

Also dont use `$_POST` laravel has built in ways of getting the values from your form.

### Laravel 5

```
$request->input('firstname');
```

like this:

```
public function users(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->input('firstname'); // This is better than using $_POST
    $lastname = $request->input('lastname');

    DB :: table("newUsers") -> insertGetId
    (
        array("firstname" => $name, "lastname" => $lastname, "email" => "test")
     );

    return view("pages.users");
}
```

Notice, I have passed in `Request $request` like a variable in the method `users`. You will also need to add `use Illuminate\Http\Request as Request;` to the top of your class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request as Request; //here

class MyController extends Controller
{
}
```

### Laravel 4

```
Input::get('firstname');
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your Form as follows:

```
<form action="{{ route("users") }}" method="post">
  <input type ="form" name=firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First name"> 
  <input type ="form" name=lastname" id="lastname">
  <input type="form" name="email" id="email">

  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

You've to provide the `name` attribute to your form fields.

And in the controller, you don't have to use `$_POST` anymore.

Just use:

```
public function users(Request $request)
{
   $firstname = $request->input('firstname');
   $lastname = $request->input('lastname');

    DB :: table("newUsers") -> insertGetId(
       array("firstname" => $name, "lastname" => $lastname, "email" => "test")
    );
    return view("pages.users");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access form data with `$request->get('first_name')`, for example.

To make it work, add `name` tags to your form `inputs` and catch data, for example, if you use store action:

```
function store(Request $request){

}
```

In this case you also can `easily` validate input data by using custom Reuqest classes:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation